# Вывести ключ из словаря

Tags: python, словарь

Мне необходимо вывести значение из словаря по заданному ключу. Ключ задается через input(). Вытащим значение по ключу 'Bye'
В простом варианте вытащить значение по ключу можно так

```
d={'Hello': 'Hi', 'Bye': 'Goodbye', 'List': 'Array'}
print(d['Bye'])
```

Получаем 'Goodbye'

Через input() я делаю так:

```
d={'Hello': 'Hi', 'Bye': 'Goodbye', 'List': 'Array'}
a = input('Введите ключ')
print(d[a])
```

Но мне выдает ошибку 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print(d[a])
KeyError: "'Bye'"

Comment: Вводите `Bye` без кавычек

Comment: И учитывайте регистр.

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде нет ошибки в данном случае. Внимательно смотрите, как вводите значения через консоль. Скорее всего, Вы ставите лишние кавычки при вводе значения,
т.е. в строке

```
a = input('Введите ключ')
```

вместо

```
"Bye"
```

вводите просто

```
Bye
```